# Phalcon framework displays index of page instead of application

Tags: php, phalcon

I wanted to use learn phalcon so i tried installing it on ubuntu. I did everything like in tutorial and i can see phalcon in phpinfo(). I made sample project like in tutorial with following htaccess files but all I can see when typing localhost/tutorial is index of /tutorial instead of Hello! message

```
#/tutorial/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule  ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


#/tutorial/public/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `<br>` tags from your .htaccess files. If the previous doesn't work check your apache configs for the localhost, maybe it doesn't `AllowOverride`.

Also you can use the steps from [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/apache.html) to create a virtual host on apache with it's document root set to the path of `tutorial` folder.

Everytime you change the configs of apache, remember to do a reload or a restart of the apache service.